# EAV - is it really bad in all scenarios?

Tags: database-design, data-structures, anti-patterns

I'm thinking to use an [entity-attribute-value (EAV) model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) for some of the stuff in one of the projects, but all [questions about it in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) end up to answers calling EAV an anti-pattern.

But I'm wondering if it is that wrong in all cases.

Let's say shop product entity, it has common features, such as name, description, image, and price, that take part in logic many places and has (semi)unique features, like watch and beach ball would be described by completely different aspects. So I think EAV would fit for storing those (semi)unique features.

All this is assuming, that for showing product list, it is enough info in product table (that means no EAV is involved) and just when showing one product/comparing up to 5 products/etc. data saved using EAV is used.

I've seen such approach in Magento commerce and it is quite popular, so are there cases when EAV is reasonable?

Comment: @busy_wait "Entity-Attibute-Value" tables - see [Entity–attribute–value model on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model).

Comment: For an example of the EAV pattern working out really well, take a look at the Datomic database. It stores everything in the EAVT pattern (T is a "timestamp", actually more like a transaction id). Their [indexing documentation](docs.datomic.com/indexes.html) seems to show it best. For an example of EAV working out terribly, see [Wordpress](http://www.antradar.com/blog-wordpress-and-the-curse-of-eav).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20140831134758/http://www.dbforums.com/database-concepts-design/1619660-otlt-eav-design-why-do-people-hate.html

EAV gives a flexibility to the developer to define the schema as needed and this is good in some circumstances.

On the other hand it performs very poorly in the case of an ill-defined query and can support other bad practices.

In other words, EAV gives you enough rope to hang yourself and in this industry, things should be designed to the lowest level of complexity because the guy replacing you on the project will likely be an idiot.

Comment: Love the last sentence.

Comment: Rotten link.  Is there a cached version somewhere?

Comment: Don't follow the link.  The page loads slowly and is not helpful.  Also, old-style forums like that stink.  Use stack overflow instead!  Upvote good/helpful answers and push down the trash.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.

Comment: Just for the sake of thoroughness, the guy who worked on the project before you, and the one replacing you on the project are likely be idiots.

Comment: In my experience, both persons preceding and replacing you is likely an idiot.

Comment: In my experience, checking the repo history often shows that I was the previous idiot, therefore I assume that I will be the future idiot also.

Comment: "...because the guy replacing you on the project will likely be an idiot." - or an AI algorithm...

Answer (score 46):

In a nutshell, EAV is useful when your list of attributes is frequently growing, or when it's so large that most rows would be filled with mostly NULLs if you made every attribute a column.  It becomes an anti-pattern when used outside of that context.

Comment: I would replace "frequently" by "needs the possibilty to be changed at run-time".

Comment: We can shorten that even further Doc Brown by using the fairly well-understood word "dynamic" - EAV is useful when your list of attributes may change dynamically.

Comment: Even further to "when your attributes may change" -- "dynamically" is a bit redundant in this context :)

Comment: Is it necessarily more useful than, say, having the form for changing an attribute perform a `CREATE TABLE` for the new attribute?

Comment: @DamianYerrick interesting approach. Have you used this in production?

Answer (score 34):

> Let's say shop product entity, it has common features, like name, description, image, price, etc., that take part in logic many places and has (semi)unique features, like watch and beach ball would be described by completely different aspects. So I think EAV would fit for storing those (semi)unique features?

Using an EAV structure for has several implications that are trade offs.

You are trading off a 'less space for the row because you don't have 100 columns that are `null`' against 'more complex queries and model'.

Having an EAV typically means the value is a string that one can stuff any data into.  This then has implications on validity and constraint checking.  Consider the situation where you've put the number of batteries used as something in the EAV table.  You want to find a flashlight that uses C sized batteries, but less than 4 of them.

```sql
select P.sku
from
  products P
  attrib Ab on (P.sku = Ab.sku and Ab.key = "batteries")
  attrib Ac on (P.sku = Ac.sku and Ac.key = "count")
where
  cast(Ac.value as int) < 4
  and Ab.value = 'C'
  ...
```

The thing to realize here is that you can't use an index reasonably on the value. You also can't prevent someone from putting in something that isn't an integer there, or an invalid integer (uses '-1' batteries) because the value column is used again and again for different purposes.

This then has implications in trying to write a model for the product.  You'll have the nice typed values... but you're also going to have a `Map<String,String>` just sitting there with all sorts of *stuff* in it.  This then has further implications when serializing it to XML or Json and the complexities of trying to do validation or queries against *those* structures.

Some alternatives or modifications to the pattern to consider is instead of a free form key, to have another table with valid keys.  It means instead of doing string comparisons in the database, you are checking against the equality of foreign key ids. Changing the key itself is done in one spot.  You've got a known set of keys which means that they can be done as an enum.

You could also have related tables that contain attributes of a specific class of product.  A grocery department could have another table that has several attributes associated with it that the building materials doesn't need (and vice versa).

```
+----------+    +--------+    +---------+
|Grocery   |    |Product |    |BuildMat |
|id (fk)   +--->|id (pk) |<---+id (fk)  |
|expiration|    |desc    |    |material |
|...       |    |img     |    |...      |
+----------+    |price   |    +---------+
                |...     |               
                +--------+
```

---

There are times that *especially* call for a EAV table.

Consider the situation where you aren't just writing a inventory system for your company where you know every product and every attribute.  You are now writing an inventory system to sell to other companies.  You *can't* know every attribute of every product - they will need to define them.

One idea that comes out is "we'll let the customer modify the table" and this is just bad (you get into meta-programming for table structures because you no longer know what is where, they can *royally* mess up the structure or corrupt the application, they've got the access to do wrong things and the implications of that access become significant).  There's more about this path at [MVC4 : How to create model at run time?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/238511/40980)

Instead, you create the administrative interface to an EAV table and allow that to be used.  If the customer wants to create an entry for 'polkadots' it goes into the EAV table and you already know how to deal with that.

An example of this can be seen in the [database model for Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/DatabaseModel) you can see the custom_fields table, and the custom_values table -- those are parts of the EAV that allows the system to be extended.

---

Note that if you find your entire table structure to look like EAV rather than relational, you might want to look at the [KV flavor of NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93Value_or_KV_stores) (cassandra, redis, Mongo,. ...).  Realize that these often come with *other* tradeoffs in their design that may or may not be appropriate to what you are using it for.  However, they are *specifically* designed with the intent of an EAV structure.

You may wish to read [SQL vs NoSQL for an inventory management system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8322525/289086)

Following this approach with a document oriented NoSQL database (couch, mongo), you could consider each inventory item to be a document on a disk... pulling up everything in a single document is fast.  Furthermore, the document is structured so that you can pull out any one single thing fast.  On the other hand, searching all the documents for things that match a particular attribute can have less performance (compare using 'grep' against all the files)... its all a trade off.

Another approach would be LDAP where one would have a base with all of its associated items, but would then also have additional object classes applied to it for the other types of items. (see [System Inventory Using LDAP](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/SA/v13/i09/a5.htm))

Once you go down this path, you *may* find something that exactly matches what you are looking for... though everything comes with some tradeoffs.

Answer (score 21):

*6 years later*

Now that [JSON in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) is here, we have another option, for those who are using Postgres. If you only want to attach some extra data to a product, then your needs are fairly simple. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE products (sku VARCHAR(30), shipping_weight REAL, detail JSON);
INSERT INTO products ('beachball', 1.0, '{"colors": ["red", "white"], "diameter": "50cm"}');

SELECT * FROM products;
    sku    | weight |               detail               
-----------+--------+------------------------------------
 beachball |      1 | {"colors": ["red", "white"], "diameter": "50cm"}
```

Here's a smoother introduction to JSON in Postgres: https://www.compose.com/articles/is-postgresql-your-next-json-database/.

Note that Postgres actually stores JSONB, not plain text JSON, and it does support indexes on fields inside of a JSONB document / field, in case you discover that you actually do want to query against that data.

Also, note that fields within a JSONB field cannot be modified individually with an UPDATE query; you would have to replace the entire content of the JSONB field.

This answer may not directly address the question, but it does offer an alternative to an EAV pattern, that should be considered by anyone who is pondering the original question.

Comment: I think it is great idea to post alternative solution. Just to keep others on track, MS SQL was supporting XML columns with ability to index them for a while and starting from 2016 it can do the same with JSON (although JSON is not a native column type in MS SQL, you can still index it). On other hand - from what I read, Postgres JSON support is better, for example it looks like it does support indexes on data in JSON array properties.

Comment: *"...fields within a JSONB field cannot be modified individually with an UPDATE query; you would have to replace the entire content of the JSONB field."*  This is outdated, isn't it?  There is a `jsonb_set()` function in Postgres 9.5 and later which is for exactly this.  (The article you linked to links in turn to a [newer article discussing the 9.5 feature additions](https://www.compose.com/articles/could-postgresql-9-5-be-your-next-json-database/).)

Answer (score 7):

Typically people look the other way if you're using it for lookup tables, or other situations where the benefit is to keep from having to create tables for one or two stored values. The situation you're describing, where you're basically storing item properties, sounds perfectly normal (and normalized). Widening a table to store a variable number of item attributes is a bad idea.

For the general case of storing disparate data in a long thin table...You shouldn't be *afraid* to create new tables if you need to, and having just one or two long skinny tables isn't much better than having only one or two short fat tables.

That being said, I am notorious for using EAV tables for logging. They do have some good utility.

Comment: Please define "skinny table" and "fat table".

Comment: @TulainsCórdova: A "skinny" table would be one with few rows, and many columns, while a fat table is one with many columns and few rows. An example would be building a lookup table where you have properties for say, books. A fat table would have one record per book, with many columns for specific pieces of data, while a thin table would have maybe four columns id,book,field_name,field_data. The advantage of the first is that there are fewer records, but the negative is that some fields may be blank, and the whole thing is harder to extend.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy I think your skinny/fat definitions are mixed up -- they are the same.  Do you mean that a skinny table has few columns and many rows?

Answer (score 6):

EAV changes the problem of explicit structure, to implied perception. Rather than saying X is a table with columns A and B. You imply that columns A and B form table X. It's the reverse in one sense but there isn't a one-to-one mapping, necessarily. You could say that A and B both map to table (or type) X and Y. This could be important in the more involved domain where context matters.

I've been studying Datomic, for this type of approach and I think it's a very useful and powerful system with limits on what you should do with it (not that you couldn't).

That EAV would be slow, or "give you enough rope to hang yourself" is not a statement I would agree with. Rather, I would put more emphasis on the strengths of EAV and if it suits your problem space, you should consider it.

My experience is that it's a wonderful *almost unconstrained* approach to modelling. Specifically, in the case of Datomic, they impose a ordered set semantic on top of everything. Any modelling decision which models a relationship can freely go from one, to many without having to redesign columns/tables. You can also go back as long as the constraint doesn't violate the invariant. It's all the same under the hood.

The problem with EAV has in my mind been with lack of an implementation like Datomic. Since this is a question about EAV I don't want to rave on about Datomic but it is one of those things where I think they got everything right with respect to EAV.

Answer (score 1):

Storing EAV as one big table with three columns `entity_id, attribute_id, value` is an inefficient implementation of EAV.
For more efficiency: **attributes should be columns**.

Create new columns or tables when new attributes are introduced. Use a query engine that can automatically pick correct tables.

As far as I know there is no library that can do it for you so you migt have to make your own.

#### Example

Here is an example how you can store EAV efficiently given these entities:
`e1,e2` has `a1,a2,a3`
`e3,e4,e5` has `a1,a5`

##### table_a1a2a3

| e | a1 | a2 | a3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| e1 | value | value | value |
| e2 | value | value | value |

##### table_a1a5

| e | a1 | a5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e3 | value | value |
| e4 | value | value |
| e5 | value | value |

You can get the flexibility of EAV and the performance of hand-crafted database models this way.

For SQL database you could imagine some procedure that picks correct tables:

| imagine query | generated SQL query |
| --- | --- |
| `SELECT a1,a2,a3` | `SELECT a1,a2,a3 FROM table_a1a2a3` |
| `SELECT a1,a5` | `SELECT a1,a5 FROM table_a1a5` |
| `SELECT a1` | `SELECT a1 FROM table_a1a2a3` + `SELECT a1 FROM table_a1a5` |
| `SELECT a1 WHERE a2 > a3` | `SELECT a1 FROM table_a1a2a3 WHERE a2 > a3` |
| `DELETE WHERE e = 1` | `DELETE FROM table_a1a2a3 WHERE e = 1` + `DELETE FROM table_a1a5 WHERE e = 1` |
| etc... | etc... |